# "sp_spaceused" returns not uptodate numbers

Tags: sql-server-express

We use "sp_spaceused" in a while-loop where we delete data.
*We do so in order to remain under the 10GB SQL Express Edition limit.*

The Delete routine that runs nightly

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeletePeriod4Data]
    @LIMIT_InMB AS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON    

    DECLARE @MinBegin AS DATETIME
    DECLARE @SizePeriod4_InMB AS FLOAT

    EXEC [dbo].[GetDatabaseStatsPeriod4MB]
        @Size_InMB = @SizePeriod4_InMB OUTPUT

    WHILE @SizePeriod4_InMB > @LIMIT_InMB
    BEGIN

        SELECT @MinBegin = MIN(MONTH.ProdData.[Begin])
        FROM MONTH.ProdData


        PRINT 'deleting from period 4, month and year of: ' 
        PRINT @MinBegin


        DELETE
        FROM Month.ProdData
        WHERE 
            Year = DATEPART(YEAR, @MinBegin)
            AND
            Month = DATEPART(MONTH, @MinBegin)


        EXEC [GetDatabaseStatsPeriod4MB]
             @Size_InMB = @SizePeriod4_InMB OUTPUT
    END

END
```

And this is the culprit stored procedure that returns outofdate numbers.

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDatabaseStatsPeriod4MB]
    @Size_InMB float OUTPUT 
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #t (name SYSNAME, rows CHAR(11), reserved VARCHAR(18),  
        data VARCHAR(18), index_size VARCHAR(18), unused VARCHAR(18)) 

    DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(0); -- <-- helps?

    EXEC sp_msforeachtable @command1=
          'INSERT INTO #t EXEC sp_spaceused ''?'', @updateUsage=''TRUE''',
          @whereand=' and schema_name(schema_id) = ''Month'' '


    SELECT @Size_InMB = 
             SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(data, 1, LEN(data)-3)))/1024.0 
    FROM #t 

    DROP TABLE #t

    PRINT 'PERIODE 4 Size (Month)'
    PRINT @Size_InMB 


END
```

What we tried is

1. Adding parameter "@updateUsage=TRUE" to sp_spaceused
2. Added call to "DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(0);"
3. Added params to "DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(0) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, COUNT_ROWS;"
4. Using a delay before I call “UpdateUsage”
   WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05' ---- 5 Second Delay

---

Generic code to repro the problem

```
CREATE TABLE #t (name SYSNAME, rows CHAR(11), reserved VARCHAR(18),  
  data VARCHAR(18), index_size VARCHAR(18), unused VARCHAR(18)) 

EXEC sp_msforeachtable @command1=
  'INSERT INTO #t EXEC sp_spaceused ''?'', @updateUsage=''TRUE'''

SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(data, 1, LEN(data)-3)))/1024.0 
  FROM #t 

DROP TABLE #t

-- Delete something in your DB (Northwind)

-- Run the above again
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to allow for time for Ghost Cleanup to handle the ghosted records since DELETE doesn't actually delete anything, it just marks the records as ghosted in the slot on the page and then it is the job of the Ghost Cleanup task to clean those up later.  You can read about this in Paul's blog posts:

[Inside the Storage Engine - Ghost Cleanup in Depth](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/inside-the-storage-engine-ghost-cleanup-in-depth.aspx)

[Ghost Cleanup - Redux](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Ghost-cleanup-redux.aspx)

[Truning off the Ghost Cleanup Task for a Performance Gain](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Turning-off-the-ghost-cleanup-task-for-a-performance-gain.aspx)

You can also track Ghost Cleanup activity with Extended Events in SQL Server 2008+ as I show in my blog post:

[Tracking Ghost Cleanup](http://sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/post/An-XEvent-a-Day-%2815-of-31%29-Tracking-Ghost-Cleanup.aspx)

You either need to wait between the delete and checking for space used to allow Ghost Cleanup to run or between the delete and the check for space used, force Ghost Cleanup by forcing an index scan as Paul explains in his blog posts.